# Есть ли ошибка в предложении из романа Л.Н. Толстого?

Tags: пунктуация

**Из романа Л.Н. Толстого** ("Война и мир". Том 1, 1868 год):

*Пьер, приехав вперед, как домашний человек, прошел в кабинет князя Андрея и тотчас же, по привычке, лег на диван, взял первую попавшуюся с полки книгу (это были Записки Цезаря) и принялся, облокотившись, читать ее из середины*.

*— Что ты сделал с m-lle Шерер? Она теперь совсем заболеет, **— сказал, входя в кабинет, князь Андрей и потирая маленькие, белые ручки.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если деепричастный оборот включает в свой состав подлежащее, то запятая отделяет весь оборот от сказуемого, а между подлежащим и деепричастием запятая не ставится.

Об этом говорится у Розенталя ([Деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113), п. 4, примечание; мне кажется, что это наш случай):

> У поэтов-классиков встречаются деепричастные обороты, включающие в свой состав подлежащее, которое не выделяется внутри оборота запятыми: ***Услышав** граф её походку и проклиная свой ночлег и своенравную красотку, в постыдный обратился бег* (П.)...

"Перестроимся": В постыдный обратился бег, услышав **граф** её походку и проклиная свой ночлег и своенравную красотку.
Тут имеются однородные деепричастные обороты — как и у Толстого.

Если бы Лев Николаевич писал свое предложение сейчас, думаю, что запятую он бы не поставил.
Но полтора века назад современных правил не было, поэтому предлагаю считать имеющуюся запятую не ошибкой, а неточностью.

Comment: Да, скорее неточностью.  Тут дело в том, что грамматика при наличии запятой не прочитывается нормально. Спасибо вам за правило. Оно мне встречалось раньше, но как-то я не обратила на него должного внимания.

Answer (score 1):

**ДЛЯ СПРАВКИ**

**Из ответа Риммы Михайловой:**

> Если бы Лев Николаевич писал свое предложение сейчас, думаю, что запятую он бы не поставил.

А Лев Николаевич, похоже на то, и тогда не ставил.

Из издания 1880 года:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Круто! Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня.  Сюжет становится интересным) А кто же и когда эти запятые  поставил? И почему у Толстого оборот вообще не обособлен?  Тоже странная грамматика.

Comment: @Sharon:   _«И почему у Толстого оборот вообще не обособлен? Тоже странная грамматика»_. === А по-моему, не странная. При отсутстствии запятых и подлежащее не оторвано от сказуемого, и союзная связь двух деепричастий лучше ощущается.

Comment: @Sharon Кто запятые поставил? Ну... Наверное, тот, кто "осовременивал" текст, тот, кто поставил и отсутствующее тире после прямой речи. Меня ещё и *Записки Цезаря* смущают.

Comment: "Сказал входя в кабинет князь Андрей и потирая руки". Кто сейчас так напишет? А с одной запятой и под наши правила и грамматику подойдет. "Сказал, входя в кабинет князь Андрей и потирая руки".  Розенталь бы одобрил)  Поэтому я за одну запятую.  Надо еще приглядеться к деепричастным оборотам того времени.

Answer (score 0):

Я могу предположить, что в приведенном предложении одна запятая является **лишней** (можно обойтись и без нее). А вот грамматика предложения при наличии запятой не просматривается ясно.

Вариант **без запятой:**

— Что ты сделал с m-lle Шерер? Она теперь совсем заболеет, — сказал, входя в кабинет(?) **князь Андрей** и потирая маленькие, белые ручки.

**Пояснение**

В предложении использована **инверсия** подлежащего ***"князь Андрей"***, исходный вариант такой:

...сказал **князь Андрей**,  входя в кабинет и потирая маленькие, белые ручки.

При инверсии вторая запятая опускается.

2. Об этом пишет Розенталь в правилах **для СПП**, но, возможно, перестановка делалась и для **деепричастных** конструкций тоже

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)

3. Если **главная часть** сложноподчиненного предложения находится внутри придаточной (в разговорном стиле речи), то запятая **обычно** ставится только после главной части (а перед ней не ставится); ср.: *Хозяйством **нельзя сказать**, чтобы он занимался…* (Г.) — ***Нельзя сказать**, чтобы он занимался хозяйством;*